# How can i choose the page number in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

What can i do to my pdf output start not in page 1 but in the page 40?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are using latex, you can put this at the begining of your Rmd, after the yaml

```
\setcounter{page}{40}
```

Comment: awesome! Don't forget to accept the answer to let people know that they could find an answer here.